# How to Copy/Clone a Virtual Environment from Server to Local Machine

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, webserver, virtualenv

I have an existing Python django Project running in Web Server. Now the client needs to make some changes in the existing code. So I need to set it up in my Local Machine. All the packages needed for this project is installed in a Virtual environment. How can I copy or clone this virtual environment to my Local machine to run this Project.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` on the remote machine
2. Copy that `requirements.txt` file to your local machine
3. In your local virtual environment, run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

And, so long as all of the requirements are well behaved Python packages, you should be good to go.

Comment: Did'nt know about pip freeze. Is that all packages that are installed on the machine. Or is it only those that are installed by pip?

Comment: All of the packages installed on the machine (or in the virtual environment you're currently in).

Comment: What if you don't want to install them again ? Can you copy installed package library in new virtual environment's location ?

Comment: What if I want to copy the entire environment to an offline computer?

Comment: This would work only for PyPI available packages right? If there are any custom libraries those would be missed isn't it

Comment: @WesleyRanger see my answer on a similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72999525/9196664

Answer (score 2):

Please using Freeze command and you will get text file with all the versions of packages.
Then install them using easy install or pip install