# Can not use packages in Virtual Environment in Linux

Tags: python, linux, django, server, virtualenv

So, I use Virtual Environment for my project python/django. I can activate the Virtual Environment in my server. Please see the below result:
[image]

But when I use the "which pip" command or "which python" command. It can not specify the pip or python in Virtual Environment. What you can see the below demo. It used the pip and python in my server instead of Virtual Environment
[image]

So what's happening? Please help me?

Thanks for your helping!

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, your virtualenv was set up based on a certain version of python. Why would you need to specify it more?

Comment: when I entered the "python manage.py runserver" command. Some modules can'nt be run. So I use "which python" or "which pip" to check it.

Comment: Virtualenv setup needs python and pip. virtualenV can only have the packages and modules of python.

Comment: No, I dont think so. I created new virtualenV  and check it with "which python" command line. It specified to python in virtualenV . Result: "/var/www/testenv/bin/python"

Comment: Yes, but you have not installed python into your virtualenv. Whenever you create a new virtualen, it creates a bin/ directory into your virtualenv with the same python running on your server.

Comment: I copied my virtualenV  from other server and It run successly before in my old server. I reliably installed python into my virtualen before.

Comment: You should re-create your virtualenv by getting packages from your original virtualenv **pip freeze > requirements.txt**. Then you re-install them by using **pip install -r requirements.txt**. I have no faith in the virtualenv copy.

Comment: Yes, let me try! Thanks @jedema

Comment: @jedema yes, you are right! This is answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207430/how-to-copy-clone-a-virtual-environment-from-server-to-local-machine

Comment: I will answer to your question for others SO users

Comment: SO users??? What's that mean?

Comment: Stackoverflow users :)

Comment: @jedema =]] Oh I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than copy a virtualenv, it's better to create a new one. To **copy your packages from your original virtualenv**, you should use :

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

In order to **re-install your packages in the final virtualenv** you use :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```