# copying an project that has an virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have to copy a couple of projects to a different server that have their own virtual environments (virtualenv).

So, what would be a good way of recreating those virtual environments on that different server, something tells me that they wont work out of the box.

Can I just delete the one that is there and make a new one? Or can I just use it even though it was copied to a different location?

Tnx,
Tom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Copy/Clone a Virtual Environment from Server to Local Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207430/how-to-copy-clone-a-virtual-environment-from-server-to-local-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete one and create new env on the other server. Just make sure you have list of dependencies. You can create this list by `activating` your environment and typing:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Later on, if you want to install those dependencies just activate new env and type

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

All libraries will be installed with proper version. Example output of the `pip freeze` command:

```
pip freeze                                            
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
ansible==2.4.0.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
certifi==2017.4.17
cffi==1.9.1
chardet==3.0.4
checksumdir==1.1.4
click==6.7
cryptography==1.7.1
```

Comment: yes I already have the requirements file, so when I create and activate the new virtualenv I will just pip install -r requirements.txt